# How can i map image data in csv format to images name in mern stack and show to users

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-redux, mern

I have been trying to make an admin panel where my client can upload images data in csv format with price of items,descriptions and cost and map the data to image name  saved in public/images in mern stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **papaparse** for parsing CSV files. You can find the docs [here](https://www.papaparse.com)